# scp upload file: no such file or directory

Tags: windows, linux, ssh, scp

I'm using ssh to connect with a linux server. I'm trying to upload a file from my own computer(windows7) to linux.
When I type scp Desktop/H5.txt xxUserNamexx@mumble-39.xxServerNamexxx:/u/private/

I got following error:
scp Desktop/H5.txt xxUserNamexx@mumble-39.xxxServerNamexxxx:/u/private/
Desktop/H5.txt: No such file or directory

I can guarantee the server name and the file directory is correct. It seems that scp cannot find my file on my local computer.

What's the default path? What path should I type if the file I'm intending to upload is on my desktop?

Thank you

Comment: Having a similar problem on Windows 10, but it's not recognizing the remote server. Really don't want to install WinSCP. And for this problem, the local filepath should use backslash, not forward slash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

winscp is a nice option to copy files from MS to *nix. Also pscp is useful. SCP have known issues when used between MS and nix. There seems to be some misunderstanding of folder structure  by scp.

Answer (score 0):

drap the H5.txt from　desktop to you cmd windows, this can avoid you type the wrong path

Comment: Still get the error:
ssh: Could not resolve hostname C: Name or service not known

Comment: I ended up using pscp. And the original path works!... have no idea why scp won't work.Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

In the future you could try using winscp when you're dealing with small files. Also I think a cygwin scp should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The slashes are incorrect. On Windows, it should be (assuming you are running Command Prompt from your Home directory):

```
C:\Users\user> scp Desktop\H5.txt junjue@mumble-39.xxServerNamexxx:/u/j/u/junjue/private/
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and fixed it for a long time. This is because you are **already logged in to the server** in the terminal.

so just

```
exit
```

Then use the scp command in the terminal and you'll be fine

Hope this helps you.